# App.css and App.js still not found in laravel 9 after npm run dev

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-9

Quite new to Laravel and I made sure I did looked into the documentations of Laravel 9 before diving but incase I missed one, I have this issue wher app.css and app.js on the the link served by artisan are not found. Boostrap scaffolds are now in the views folder but it seems like the (quite unsure about this) the app.js & app.css are still inaccessible so bootstrap doesnt work. I made sure to run npm install and npm run dev after the bootstrap and boostrap --auth installation from artisan. As of now the project is totally fresh so it works except the boostrap won't load because of the 404 error. Here are some snapshots of the projects including the running terminal sessions. [image][image][image] [image]

Commands used in sequence:

1. `composer require laravel/ui --dev`
2. `php artisan ui bootstrap`
3. `php artisan ui boostrap --auth`
4. `npm install`
5. `npm run dev`

All of the threads I've looked here in SO are stating they're not running npm dev which I am running already but I still haven't manage to find a working solution.

Comment: Carefully read https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite; L9 just switched to Vite, and its `npm run dev` variant doesn't actually create app.js/app.css files, it serves them internally. For this to work, you have to [load your CSS/scripts](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/vite#loading-your-scripts-and-styles) via `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])`.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh thanks man. Really appreaciated, now I can confirm I am dumb. Just to make sure I understand this right. I will run npm dev, then load the assets using the vite directive on the head only. Do I need to import it on every blade that needs it or a component works fine with it?

Comment: Anyway, it's finally fixed thanks.

Comment: You'd typically have the `@vite` in your app's main layout blade file.

Answer (score 3):

You can follow below steps:

**create project with laravel**

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel "project name"
```

install laravel UI for bootstrap 5

```
composer require laravel/ui
```

Generate login / registration scaffolding with bootstrap 5

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

import bootstrap 5 path in vite.config.js

```
import path from 'path';

resolve:{
       alias:{
           '~bootstrap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/bootstrap'),
       }
   }
```

import bootstrap 5 scss in js folder

```
 import '../sass/app.scss';

 import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
```

use @vite blade directive in your template

```
 @vite(['resources/js/app.js'])
```

finally build your asset file.

```
 npm run build
```

and then run project using artisan command.

```
php artisan serve
```